# Необходимость использования библиотек android support

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Я пишу приложение под api 21 и выше (android 5.0 и выше).

Могу ли я безболезненно убрать из app.gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

и из классов активити `extends AppCompatActivity`, либо же после удаления этих строк будут проблемы?

Приложение уже в релизе, поэтому хочется минимизировать риски. У самого есть возможность теста только на android 9, ну и на эмуляторах.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На данный момент `support` библиотеки, не означают поддержку старых версий. Эти библиотеки нужны и для поддержки апи 21 и выши. В разных версиях андроида, апи работы с разными компонентами может меняться. `Support` библиотеки предоставляют общее решения для всех версий. Вам самим не нужно проверять версии анроида, все это уже написано в либе. Посмотрите внутрь `WorkManager` например.
Сейчас, после объединения библиотек в androidx, туда входят также компоненты из `JetPack`